# Jquery ScrollTo webpage Google Index

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, scrollto

I would like to build a website where when you go to the next pag, 
the page slides to the next.

I can use Jquery.ScrollTo but then i have to load all the pages at ones.
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/
This is not a good result for the google index I think.

What is the best way to do this? I think about loading the next page with ajax.

Comment: Search engines can not read AJAX, because most search engines won't read most JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need includes having HTML links for your navigation, ensuring that your site works on browsers that do not have JavaScript turned on, and using real links in your JavaScript or AJAX, such as:

`[a href=”ajax.htm?sn=products” onClick=”navigate(‘ajax.html#sn=products′); return false”]products[/a]`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the JQuery mobile framework which has this implemented.  They use Ajax page loads and CSS3 transitions to slide new pages into view but your page HTML uses normal  tags which can be used by a search spider.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html